# Are partial answers in comments permissisble?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

I asked a [question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/62727/do-the-individual-builders-listed-in-nehemiah-3-represent-larger-household-group?noredirect=1#comment126286_62727) on this stack yesterday.

The only 'answer' I've received up to now is a very short, poorly evidenced comment. The stack I'm most active on is [the one for roleplaying games](https://www.rpg.stackexchange.com), where partial answers in comments are [explicitly discouraged](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6534/60918). As such, my initial instinct was to reply to the comment, asking the commenter to refrain from answering in comments and to justify their answer more fully within the format of an answer-proper. I've refrained from doing so because I've been unable to find guidance for this stack along those lines.

Are answers-in-comments to be discouraged on this stack?

Comment: Yes they're discouraged, and we often deleted comments, but we don't watch every question intently to delete them all as soon as we can.

Comment: @curiousdannii are you affirming that we discourage partial answers in comments via a partial answer in the comments?

Comment: Well Meta doesn't operate by the same rules ;)